# Create AdHoc Distribution for iOS app

Tags: ios

I'm newbie. I have any questions about creating AdHoc Distribution for iOS application:

1. If I use AdHoc Distribution, do I need to release my app. I mean I need upload my app to AppStore?
2. After creating AdHoc Distribution, I just sent a binary file to other testers? I don't need send the source code?
3. If want create AdHoc Distribution, I need account develop IOS. I used this account to login and add UDID? Can you show me step by step how to create AdHoc Distribution and adding UDID?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you check this **https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html**

Comment: Go to https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action and check   Development Resources

Comment: @Chandu-Indyaah: Thanks, I'm reading that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I use AdHoc Distribution, do I need to release my app. I mean I need upload my app to AppStore?

**No.**

> After creating AdHoc Distribution, I just sent a binary file to other testers? I don't need send the source code?

**Right.** The distribution profile that you create tells the device that it's okay to run the app. An Ad Hoc profile includes the device IDs of the devices to which you are distributing the app. Ad Hoc is used mainly for distributing your app to a limited number of people for testing -- it's unwieldy for real-world distribution.

> If want create AdHoc Distribution, I need account develop IOS. I used this account to login and add UDID? Can you show me step by step how to create AdHoc Distribution and adding UDID?

**Yes,** you need an account to run your app on the device whether you're distributing via Ad Hoc distribution or even just developing the app.

I'm not going to take the time to write a step-by-step tutorial because Apple's instructions are pretty clear on this topic, and there are plenty of tutorials on the web already as well. If you're having difficulty with something specific, feel free to ask about that.

Answer (score -2):

First create .ipa file than open http://www.diawi.com site and then

drag your ipa file to upload box then press send .At this time you will get one url.
Give this url other to infall that app.Enjoy